# Meaning of "Bring out the devil inside me"

Tags: meaning

I'm trying to understand one of sentence from song.

"Oh baby you bring out the devil inside me"

The "bring out" is not clear for me

1. Can I replace word "bring out" by "expose" and the meaning of the sentence will remain the same?
2. Or is it more like: you letting go out of the devil who is inside me?

Sorry if I wrote something wrong - I'm still learning English. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: No, expose doesn't work because it suggests that that devil doesn't just come out but also then wreaks havoc.

Comment: Hello, Daru. Our sister site, ELL, was created specifically to help those still learning English at a fairly basic level (we never stop). // This is a difficult area (not just the English involved). To many people, there are good and bad tendencies within all humans, and the song is doubtless saying 'I lust after you when I see you'.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bring%20out

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/bring-out

Comment: to bring out the x in someone=to **cause** the x to emerge. "She brings out the goodness in people." For example.

Answer (score 1):

My sense is reflected in the colloquial **devil**:   [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/51468?rskey=9BhyKR&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> colloquial. Fighting spirit, wildness; temper or energy that can be
>   roused; mischievousness.

So I would interpret the phrase as:

Oh baby you allow my **wild side**, my **energy**, my **mischievousness** to come to light, to being, to the surface (to be brought out).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use expose but with context.

If a woman isn’t good for you and constantly makes you rage, shout or other things of the sort then you could say “She brings the devil out of me”.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).